# Estoy tratando de leer un XML generado a partir de microsoft dynamics ax 2009

Tags: xml, dynamics-ax

Estoy viendo los datos de cada tabla y estoy tratando de identificar el primary key de cada una. Estoy usando un editor de texto (sublime text).

¿Alguien puede decirme cómo se llama este campo en el XML, o cómo lo identifico? por fa,

Esta es una tabla:

```xml
<CloudTable Name="Currency" PhysicalName="aCurrency" Class="Table" Type="Base" OriginalName="CURRENCY" Schema="dbo" CreationTime="635870068771784760" LastUpdatedTime="635885477912288415" BuildBehavior="Sync" Guid="ae8354d54LQAace86LQAa4840LQAa8aabLQAa96018fea168c">
    <CloudTable.ConnectionProperties>
      <DatabaseConnectionProperties assembly="Prism.Libraries.QuestionComposition" type="Prism.Libraries.QuestionComposition.Databases.DatabaseConnectionProperties" TimeOut="30" Database="AX2012R2" Server="localhost" Port="-1" Schema="dbo" Table="CURRENCY" IsUsingDirectConnection="False" ServiceId="" Provider="sql" Culture="1045" />
    </CloudTable.ConnectionProperties>
    <CloudTable.Query>
      <TableWhereColumnQuery assembly="Prism.Libraries.QuestionComposition" type="Prism.Libraries.QuestionComposition.Databases.TableWhereColumnQuery" IsExecutingReader="True" IsUserDefined="False" ColumnName="" Operator="EqualTo" Schema="dbo" Table="CURRENCY" RowLimit="-1" />
    </CloudTable.Query>
    <CloudTable.Cols>
      <Columns>
        <Column Name="CURRENCYCODE" PhysicalName="aCURRENCYCODE" Type="Base" DataType="Text" DataSize="65536" NumericPrecision="0" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="CURRENCYCODE" OriginalDataType="NVarChar" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="True" IsAvailable="True" LastUpdatedTime="635870068903483941" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="CURRENCYCODEISO" PhysicalName="aCURRENCYCODEISO" Type="Base" DataType="Text" DataSize="65536" NumericPrecision="0" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="CURRENCYCODEISO" OriginalDataType="NVarChar" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863531679" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ISEURO" PhysicalName="aISEURO" Type="Base" DataType="Int" DataSize="4" NumericPrecision="10" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="ISEURO" OriginalDataType="Int" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863531679" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="MODIFIEDDATETIME" PhysicalName="aMODIFIEDDATETIME" Type="Base" DataType="Timestamp" DataSize="8" NumericPrecision="0" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="MODIFIEDDATETIME" OriginalDataType="DateTime" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863531679" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="PARTITION" PhysicalName="aPARTITION" Type="Base" DataType="BigInt" DataSize="8" NumericPrecision="19" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="PARTITION" OriginalDataType="BigInt" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="RECID" PhysicalName="aRECID" Type="Base" DataType="BigInt" DataSize="8" NumericPrecision="19" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="RECID" OriginalDataType="BigInt" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="RECVERSION" PhysicalName="aRECVERSION" Type="Base" DataType="Int" DataSize="4" NumericPrecision="10" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="RECVERSION" OriginalDataType="Int" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDINGPRECISION" PhysicalName="aROUNDINGPRECISION" Type="Base" DataType="Decimal" DataSize="17" NumericPrecision="32" NumericScale="16" OriginalName="ROUNDINGPRECISION" OriginalDataType="Decimal" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDOFFPRICE" PhysicalName="aROUNDOFFPRICE" Type="Base" DataType="Decimal" DataSize="17" NumericPrecision="32" NumericScale="16" OriginalName="ROUNDOFFPRICE" OriginalDataType="Decimal" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDOFFPURCH" PhysicalName="aROUNDOFFPURCH" Type="Base" DataType="Decimal" DataSize="17" NumericPrecision="32" NumericScale="16" OriginalName="ROUNDOFFPURCH" OriginalDataType="Decimal" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDOFFSALES" PhysicalName="aROUNDOFFSALES" Type="Base" DataType="Decimal" DataSize="17" NumericPrecision="32" NumericScale="16" OriginalName="ROUNDOFFSALES" OriginalDataType="Decimal" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDOFFTYPEPRICE" PhysicalName="aROUNDOFFTYPEPRICE" Type="Base" DataType="Int" DataSize="4" NumericPrecision="10" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="ROUNDOFFTYPEPRICE" OriginalDataType="Int" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDOFFTYPEPURCH" PhysicalName="aROUNDOFFTYPEPURCH" Type="Base" DataType="Int" DataSize="4" NumericPrecision="10" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="ROUNDOFFTYPEPURCH" OriginalDataType="Int" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="ROUNDOFFTYPESALES" PhysicalName="aROUNDOFFTYPESALES" Type="Base" DataType="Int" DataSize="4" NumericPrecision="10" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="ROUNDOFFTYPESALES" OriginalDataType="Int" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863541688" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="SYMBOL" PhysicalName="aSYMBOL" Type="Base" DataType="Text" DataSize="65536" NumericPrecision="0" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="SYMBOL" OriginalDataType="NVarChar" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="False" IsAvailable="False" LastUpdatedTime="635870068863551696" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
        <Column Name="CURRENCYNAME" PhysicalName="aCURRENCYNAME" Type="Base" DataType="Text" DataSize="65536" NumericPrecision="0" NumericScale="0" OriginalName="TXT" OriginalDataType="NVarChar" IsDescriptive="False" IsVisible="True" IsAvailable="True" LastUpdatedTime="635870147608634956" CreationTime="0" OriginalDataSize="0" OriginalNumericPrecision="0" OriginalNumericScale="0" IsVirtuallyMerged="False" />
      </Columns>
    </CloudTable.Cols>
    <CloudTable.AttachedData>
      <Default />
    </CloudTable.AttachedData>
    <CloudTable.Attachment>
      <TableViewModel assembly="Prism.Core.Abacus.UI" type="Prism.Core.Abacus.UI.Diagram.ViewModels.TableViewModel">
        <TableViewModel.DiagramHostViewModel>
          <vmLmnt assembly="Prism.Vizu" type="Prism.Vizu.ViewModels.vmLmnt" X="5970.76900593695" Y="-216.926148691612" W="220" H="413" />
        </TableViewModel.DiagramHostViewModel>
      </TableViewModel>
    </CloudTable.Attachment>
  </CloudTable>
```

Comment: Si agregas el xml te podemos ayudar mas

Comment: ya hice el update, puse el xml de una tabla

Comment: Hola @carlospalacios. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No parecería estar marcado de ninguna forma. ¿Tiene un PK la tabla? Además, ¿cómo obtuviste este XML? Y ¿cuál es el objetivo, simplemente identificarlo visualmente o procesarlo por código y en qué lenguaje de programación?

Comment: que tal @Mariano fijate que me dieron el xml solo asi, me dijeron que por fa identificara el nombre de las tablas y de ser posible los primary keys, en todo el archivo no hay ni una palabra que sea "pk", "primary", "key" ni nada

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que veo la tabla es **Currency**, también comentas que esto es de **AX 2009**. La tabla **Currency** estándar de **AX 2009** tiene como **Primary key** el campo `CurrencyCode`. En el XML no figura esa info.
Estimo que nadie le cambio la **Primary key** asique tu **Primary key** tiene que ser el campo `CurrencyCode`.

Comment: Gracias !! buscare cada tabla por separado